# Error Shutting down JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, solaris, port

I am running JBOSS on Solaris10 and trying to shutdown and restart the JBOSS.  When I restart the JBOSS I am getting the following error.
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use:33409

I got this problem before and used to kill the process id related to the port 33409 using the lsof command.  Unfortunately the lsof command is not working in my solaris box.  Is there any other command I can use to identify the process id related to the port number 33409 and kill that process id, so that I can restart the JBOSS without any port conflicts.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `<JAVA_HOME>/bin/jps -lvm` to see all java processes with their main class and all its arguments and JVM arguments.

`jps -lvm | grep 'org.jboss.Main'` -- this is how I usually find PIDs of any running jboss processes.

Comment: great, this is exactlys what I was using for! Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the correct process with something like this:

```
$ ps -feA | grep "jboss"
```

It takes a bit of guesswork, but you´ll get the hang of it. Make sure you identify the correct process before killing it, though.

Comment: I tried this command and there are no processes showing up related to jboss or JBOSS.  So my problem is not solved.

Comment: try running it again, but instead of "jboss" use "java" or "jdk". Again, use your best judgement to identify the correct process to kill, since it's possible that the command returns several results

Comment: I tried again killing pretty much all the processes related to java or jdk and no luck again.  I am getting the same error.

Comment: OK, try running `netstat -o`, that should give you a list with ports and pids

Comment: Solaris does not have the -o option.  The only option I could use to is > netstat -na | grep 33409                             
71.44.35.107.33409         *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN
>
This option not giving the process id.  Any other way you think of.

Comment: Try with the options `-a` and/or `-s` (sorry, I don't have access to s Solaris box to try them myself)

Comment: Or, install `lsof` in Solaris, [here](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2008/06/10/how-to-find-pid-listening-particular-port-on-linuxsolaris-10/) is how

Comment: The link you provided was helpful and I fully understand the problem and the script provided in the link gives the process id of the port.  Thanks for your help.